# C# Specflow Object reference not set to an instance of an object in

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, specflow, google-geocoder

I am trying to implement Specflow for google geo code api, however I am repeatedly getting *System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.* and RootObject is always set to null. Can somebody help me?
below is my Step definition

```
namespace NUnit.Tests1.StepDefinition
{
[Binding]
public sealed class GoogleSteps
{
    private string googleapiurl;
    private RootObject root = new RootObject();

    [Given(@"Google api that takes address and returns latitude and longitude")]
    public void GivenGoogleApiThatTakesAddressAndReturnsLatitudeAndLongitude()
    {
        googleapiurl = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=";
    }

    [When(@"The client Gets response by ""(.*)""")]
    public async Task WhenTheClientGetsResponseBy(string addr)
    {
        HttpClient cl = new HttpClient();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(googleapiurl);
        sb.Append(addr);
        Uri uri = new Uri(sb.ToString());
        var response = await cl.GetStringAsync(uri);    
        root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response);

    }

    [Then(@"The ""(.*)"" and ""(.*)"" returned should be as expected")]
    public void ThenTheAndReturnedShouldBeAsExpected(string exp_lat, string exp_lng)
    {
        var location = root.results[0].geometry.location;
        var latitude = location.lat;
        var longitude = location.lng;
        Console.WriteLine("Testing upali");
        Console.WriteLine("location: lat " + location.lat);
        Console.WriteLine("location: long " + location.lng);
        Assert.AreEqual(location.lat.ToString(), exp_lat);
        Assert.AreEqual(location.lng.ToString(), exp_lng);
    }

}
```

}

The Json response is :

```
{
"results": [
{
"address_components": [
 {
 "long_name": "1600",
 "short_name": "1600",
  "types": [
        "street_number"
      ]
    },
    {
      "long_name": "Amphitheatre Parkway",
      "short_name": "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
      "types": [
        "route"
      ]
    },
    {
      "long_name": "Mountain View",
      "short_name": "Mountain View",
      "types": [
        "locality",
        "political"
      ]
    },
    {
      "long_name": "Santa Clara County",
      "short_name": "Santa Clara County",
      "types": [
        "administrative_area_level_2",
        "political"
      ]
    },
    {
      "long_name": "California",
      "short_name": "CA",
      "types": [
        "administrative_area_level_1",
        "political"
      ]
    },
    {
      "long_name": "United States",
      "short_name": "US",
      "types": [
        "country",
        "political"
      ]
    },
    {
      "long_name": "94043",
      "short_name": "94043",
      "types": [
        "postal_code"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "formatted_address": "1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA",
  "geometry": {
    "location": {
      "lat": 37.4223329,
      "lng": -122.0844192
    },
    "location_type": "ROOFTOP",
    "viewport": {
      "northeast": {
        "lat": 37.4236818802915,
        "lng": -122.0830702197085
      },
      "southwest": {
        "lat": 37.4209839197085,
        "lng": -122.0857681802915
      }
    }
  },
  "place_id": "ChIJ2eUgeAK6j4ARbn5u_wAGqWA",
  "types": [
    "street_address"
  ]
  }
  ],
"status": "OK"
}
```

And my RootObject class is as below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace NUnit.Tests1.GoogleAPI
{
public class RootObject
{
    public List<Result> results { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}
}
```

Result StackTrace:

```
Test Name:  VerifyLatitudeAndLongitude
Test FullName:           NUnit.Tests1.FeatureFiles.GoogleGeoCodeFeature.VerifyLatitudeAndLongitude
Test Source:    C:\Users\nandyu\documents\visual studio   
2015\Projects\NUnit.Tests1\NUnit.Tests1\FeatureFiles\GoogleGeoCode.feature :     
line 5
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:00.069

Result StackTrace:  
at 
   NUnit.Tests1.StepDefinition.GoogleSteps.ThenTheAndReturnedShouldBeAsExpected(String exp_lat, String exp_lng) in C:\Users\nandyu\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\NUnit.Tests1\NUnit.Tests1\StepDefinition\GoogleSteps.cs:line 42
at lambda_method(Closure , IContextManager , String , String )
at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Bindings.BindingInvoker.InvokeBinding(IBinding binding,    
IContextManager contextManager, Object[] arguments, ITestTracer testTracer,    TimeSpan& duration)
at    TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStepMatch(BindingMatch match, Object[] arguments)
at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStep(StepInstance stepInstance)
at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.OnAfterLastStep()
at TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunner.CollectScenarioErrors()
at NUnit.Tests1.FeatureFiles.GoogleGeoCodeFeature.ScenarioCleanup()
at 
NUnit.Tests1.FeatureFiles.GoogleGeoCodeFeature.VerifyLatitudeAndLongitude()   
in C:\Users\nandyu\documents\visual studio 
  2015\Projects\NUnit.Tests1\NUnit.Tests1\FeatureFiles\GoogleGeoCode.feature:line 8
Result Message: System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "and the object "root" is set to null whenever I run this code but there is no error when the line "root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);" is executed" - and could you provide the stack trace, please? We can't tell where the exception is being thrown. Any diagnostics you've got would be helpful, too...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: What does your "Result" object look like; more importantly, does it match the result in the json - seems it's more a case of deserialization not happening.

Comment: I'd be creating a simple example test that has that hardcoded json response string in  it and then trying to deserialize it into a `RootObject` and taking it from there. There is obviously some difference between your definition of a `RootObject` or a `Result` and what comes back over the wire. Try extracting a `Result` node from the json and deserializing that first maybe?

Comment: Which SpecFlow version are you using? Support for async Task- bindings is only in the current 2.2 ci builds.

Comment: Jon Skeet, What I meant was the RootObject returns null, I have provided the stack trace

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is likely that you have made your step `async` when this is not supported by specflow, so your method

`public async Task WhenTheClientGetsResponseBy(string addr)`

is probably returning on this line:

```
var response = await cl.GetStringAsync(uri);
```

and specflow is not waiting on the task, so its then continuing to the next step and then your `root.results[0]` is not set to anything, so null reference exception

Answer (score 1):

Sam Holder, you are right,

I changed the code :

```
var response = await cl.GetStringAsync(uri);
```

To:

```
response = cl.GetStringAsync(uri).Result;
```

This solved my problem.